# Unable to locate dynamic button on dialog box

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I try to locate a dynamic button element after click search but it cannot locate it. The Create Account CID sometimes is not clickable and sometime can click.

```
<div class="pzbtn-rgt" data-click="...">
<div class="pzbtn-mid" data-click="....">
<img src="https://10.204.137.86:5111/prweb/PRWebLDAP3/SstGGrXNazw%5B*/webwb/zblankimage.gif" alt="" class="pzbtn-i">
Create Individual CID
<img alt="" src="https://10.204.137.86:5111/prweb/PRWebLDAP3/SstGGrXNazw%5B*/webwb/zblankimage.gif" class="pzbtn-i">
```

The create individual CID is the one need clicks on. 
I using absolute xpath but it still fails. I had tried with many ways. Please help. Thanks.

```
WebDriverWait waitCIDBtn = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
waitCIDBtn.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/span/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/span/button/div/div/div/div")));
WebElement createCID = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/span/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/span/button/div/div/div/div"));
createCID.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to invoke `click()` on the element so, instead of using `visibilityOfElementLocated()` you need use **`elementToBeClickable()`** and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.pzbtn-mid>img.pzbtn-i[src*='zblankimage']"))).click();
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='pzbtn-mid']/img[@class='pzbtn-i' and contains(@src, 'zblankimage')]"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Great , can you update the question with your current code trials and error stack trace please?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.cssSelector: div.pzbtn-mid>img.pzbtn-i[src*='zblankimage'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: The element is not visible at first but after search then it will visible.

Comment: @nicholas _TimeoutException_ is the outcome of **failed** _ExpectedConditions_. Debug your code through  `findElement()` inconjunction with `Thread.sleep()`. If you are able to locate the element, update the question with the observations.